# OpenVPN client not working on a GCE instance

Tags: openvpn, google-cloud-platform

I have set up an OpenVPN client config in my GCE instance and it's able to establish the connection correctly and finally creates a tunnel interface. 
But I cannot ping anything through that tunnel(using ping -I tun0 8.8.8.8 or curl www.google.com --interface tun0 won't get a respond). 
I tried different subnet IP range(10.8.x.x or 192.168.x.x), different protocol(TCP or UDP), different auth method(TLS or static-key) but still no any luck.

If I configure an OpenVPN server config on the instance then it's working correctly, server(the GCE instance) and clients can ping each other.
Is OpenVPN client on GCE not supported or are there anything I've missed to configure?

It seems that operating systems and configs are irrelavent. I've tried multiple instances with different OSes, or change configs(these configs are working on other VPS), but the problem insists.

More detail on Google groups gce-discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/0KoMnaojG6E

Update:
I noticed when I ping something through the tunnel the RX and TX counts change(don't know if this means icmp packages actually transfer correctly) but ping still telling me 100% packet loss. 
ifconfig before ping:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:192.168.179.21  P-t-P:192.168.179.22  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:1661 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

ping:

```
[root@mario-vps mario]# ping -I tun0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.179.21 tun0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 870ms
```

ifconfig after ping:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:192.168.179.21  P-t-P:192.168.179.22  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:1745 (1.7 KiB)  TX bytes:84 (84.0 b)
```

If I write "ping" and "ping-restart" arguments in the config file the connection won't go down. Don't know if this means even openvpn daemon is considering connection is well, but ping and curl-like stuff never work for me through that tunnel.

Comment: Is your server set up to NAT for the OpenVPN subnet?

Comment: Everything on server is OK because I can connect to server and ping Internet through tunnel with no problem on other VM machine. My GCE instance acts as a client, not a server. I've already set up iptables config working on other VMs for GCE instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on OpenVPN running on GCE instances. It works without any issues.
Please post log(snippet) whTunnel interface creates on GCE instance. Based on that logs we can easliy identify what the issue is. Usually log will be appended in syslog(if your GCE instance is Ubuntu). 
Are you planning to route your GCE instance Internet through Tunnel Interface?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to route some IP through the tunnel. My instance is CentOS, I checked /var/log/messages and I found "martian source 192.168.179.21 from 8.8.8.8, on dev tun0" logs, one line for each ping ICMP packet. I then searched the web and changed net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter/net.ipv4.conf.$IF.arp_filter/net.ipv4.conf.$IF.log_martians in /etc/sysctl.conf to 0($IF represents all interface name I could found by ifconfig) but still no luck, ping still not respond(that martian log was gone).

Comment: Your server.conf in OpenVPN Server should have `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` and `push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"`

Comment: server.conf do have these push parameters. It also push route configurations(`ip route` stuff). But I have to use `--route-noexec` and `--route-nopull` to ignore them, otherwise I will lose my SSH connection--all traffics are routed to the tunnel but nothing can go through that tunnel, I have to restart my instance. Server is not mine so I can't modify server.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a GCE instance. At runtime this solved it for me:

`for i in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter; do
    echo 2 > "$i"
done`

To test it works:

`[root@instance]# ping -I tun0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.2.50.57 tun0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=94.6 ms`

To make it persistent, you will need to:

- update any existing rp_fiter overrides:

`grep rp_filter /etc/sysctl.d/*`

- edit the /etc/sysctl.conf file and add the overrides there

`net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=2`

The value 2 is explained here https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt:

> 2 - Loose mode as defined in RFC3704 Loose Reverse Path
>         Each incoming packet's source address is also tested against the FIB
>         and if the source address is not reachable via any interface
>         the packet check will fail.